# How do a add to scrollTop based on the intended scroll distance of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/88N4d/9/

**The behavior I'm trying to accomplish:**

1. The Sidebar(s) should be fixed on the page if there is enough room
   for them
2. The Sidebar(s) should scroll if there is ever not enough room for them
3. When scrolling down, and the bottom of the sidebar(s) is reached, it should stop scrolling
4. When scrolling down, the sidebar(s) should also scroll down, until
   the bottom of the sidebar(s) is/are reached
5. When scrolling up, and the top of the sidebar(s) is reached, it should stop scrolling
6. If at any point during the scrolling of the content, the user switches directions of scrolling, the sidebar(s) shall also move in the same direction as the rest of the page / content
7. When scrolling up, the sidebar(s) should also scroll up, until the
   top of the sidebar(s) is/are reached
8. *If the content is shorter than the sidebar(s), the sidebar(s) should
   still be able to scroll* **This is the one that I'm having trouble
   with**

How do I make it so that I can detect the intended scroll distance desired by the user, rather than use the actual scrolled distance of the content body? There may be another solution, but this is all I can think of for right now.

I'm currently using Chrome on Mac.

UPDATE:

something I've noticed: using the track pad on macs does the stretching / bouncy scrolling shenanigans on the edges.. which messes up this javascript hard core. It's possible to scroll the sidebar completely off the screen if you bounce up enough times. Mouse Wheel scrolling does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’d be much better off positioning the columns `absolute` and then check positions onscroll and toggle the positions.

It gets quite complicated, since the scroll will jump if both columns are fixed and the content has regular flow.

I created a solution for you using a simpler logic that goes:

```
var $win = $(window);
var $containers = $(".container").css('position','absolute');

// we need to force a height to the body for fixed positioning
$('body').css('minHeight', Math.max.apply( Math, $containers.map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
})));

$win.bind("resize scroll", function() {
    var scrolled = $win.scrollTop(),
        winheight = $win.height(),
        elheight = 0;
    $containers.each(function() {
        elheight = $(this).height();
        $(this).css('position', function() {
            if ( elheight > (winheight+scrolled) ) {
                $(this).css('top',0);
                return 'absolute';
            }
            $(this).css('top', Math.min(0, winheight-elheight));
            return 'fixed';
        });
    });
});
```

It should fill your requirements. The fixed positioning kicks in if the columns are shorter than the window height, or if the scrollTop is enough.

A demo in all it’s glory: http://jsfiddle.net/mb9qC/

Comment: in this demo, the sidebar doesn't scroll back up as you scroll the page up =\ (at least until you are are almost near the top again.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, the sidebars does scroll back up when you scroll to the top. Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: I want it to scroll up as your scroll up. not wait until you almost get to the top to start scrolling up again =p (my demo does this :) )